# Scan all possible files on server (Brute force Filenames)

Tags: webserver, http, brute-force, web-scanners, enumeration

I'm looking for a tool which can scan all possible filename combinations on a server and tells you what filenames the server responded to.

So it would try something like: `example.com/a`, `example.com/b`, ... , `example.com/css`, ... .

It would the check if the answer from the server is a 403 or something like that and try the next one.

Comment: dirbuster https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_DirBuster_Project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [DirBuster](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_DirBuster_Project) where you can feed wordlists and it'll try to brute force file and directory names.

[Nikto](https://cirt.net/Nikto2) also checks for commonly used folder and file names on a web server.

It is not possible to check every file and folder name, however running the above tools will give you a decent amount of enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DirBuster and Nikto already mentioned, [Nmap](http://nmap.org) has several NSE scripts that could help with this and similar tasks:

- [`http-enum`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-enum.html) - Makes lots of requests for common directories, files, and other goodies. It can also [use Nikto's database](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2013/q4/292) to perform most of the same checks.
- [`http-config-backup`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-config-backup.html) - Checks for accessible config files for various frameworks, including backup extensions and editor swap files.
- [`http-userdir-enum`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-userdir-enum.html) - Enumerates usernames used with Apache's `mod_userdir` or similar extensions. Most of the time, these are valid URLs, too.
- [`http-favicon`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-favicon.html) - Retrieves the favicon.ico of the target and compares it to a list of known icons to determine server or web framework.
- [`http-waf-fingerprint`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-waf-fingerprint.html) - Detects and fingerprints different Web Application Firewalls (WAFs) based on their modification of requests and responses.
- [`http-php-version`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-php-version.html) - Determines the version of PHP running on the target using easter-egg requests.
- [`http-default-accounts`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-default-accounts.html) - Attempts to log in to various devices and frameworks with default credentials.

There are many more, including enumerators for [WordPress plugins](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-wordpress-plugins.html), [Drupal modules](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-drupal-modules.html), [IIS short file names (8.3)](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-iis-short-name-brute.html), [Gitweb projects](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-gitweb-projects-enum.html), etc.

To be fair, most dedicated [web scanners](http://sectools.org/tag/web-scanners/) will have similar functionality built in: [w3af](http://w3af.org/), [Netsparker](https://www.netsparker.com/), [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/), and others.

Answer (score 0):

[URL Fuzzer](https://pentest-tools.com/website-vulnerability-scanning/discover-hidden-directories-and-files) might do what you're looking for. It's a web app that can scan any URL for accessible directories or files with a specified extension. Do note that you can only do a limited amount of scans for free.